# Discrete-time linear control with linear state/input constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

Given a controllable discrete-time linear system

$x(k+1) = A x(k) + B u(k)$

the input sequence leading from state $x_0$ to $x_f$ is given by $C^{-1} (x_f - A^n x_0)$ where $C$ is the controllability matrix.

Suppose we add linear state/input constraints to the system, i.e.,

$W \left( \begin{matrix} x(k) \\ u(k) \end{matrix} \right) \leq b ~~ \forall k$

Given a state pair $x_0$, $x_f$, is there a result by which we can determine whether a feasible input sequence exists to go from $x_0$ to $x_f$  and if so can the input sequence be determined independent of its length?

Note that the bounded version of this question, namely whether an input sequence of length $N$ exists that leads from $x_0$ to $x_f$ can be easily expressed as a linear program.

Comment: I believe this is also used in model predictive control, but I am not that familiar with it, but I thought it was called something like maximal constraint admissible set. The only thing I can say for sure is that minimal $N$ such that $x_f$ can be reached from $x_0$ will depend on $x_0$ and $x_f$ when adding those constraints.